# SQL query "select ...where select..." take too long time

Tags: sql, performance

How can i improve performance of this query?

```
DECLARE @Form nvarchar(200)
SET @Form=N'mail'

select t1.* from dbo.EDWordForms t1
where t1.CanonicForm in
(
    SELECT CanonicForm 
        FROM  dbo.EDWordForms t2
        WHERE t2.WordForm=@Form)
```

Thanks for the answers, problem solved - there were no index on field "CanonicForm"

Comment: run both query separately and let's know which query is slower. How many records table contains?

Comment: Vicky Thakor, 3 million records, the outer query is much more slower and i'm not able to change table design ((

Comment: Maybe change this query to JOIN instead of subquery? And index on WordForm?

Comment: It's important to know more about your indexes.  If CanonicForm is not indexed, then you're stuck with a table scan, however you write your query.  And scanning 3 million records is not particularly quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, problem solved - there were no index on field "CanonicForm"

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, an explicit `join` or `exists` is more efficient than `in`.  I would try:

```
select t1.*
from dbo.EDWordForms t1
where EXISTS (SELECT CanonicForm 
              FROM dbo.EDWordForms t2
              WHERE t2.WordForm = @Form AND t1.CanonicForm = t2.CanonicForm
             );
```

Indexes can also help the query.  For your version (with `in`), you want an index on `EDWordForms(WordForm, CanonicForm)`.  For the version with `exists` (or with a `join`), the best index is `EDWordForms(CanonicForm, WordForm)`.

Comment: thanks, but same result

Comment: compare query plans between the two. Did you or didn't you create indexes?

Comment: @AlekDepler . . . Is `WordForm` declared as `nvarchar()`?  If the types are not the same, then the index will probably not be used.  You should declare the variable to be the same type as the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Prepared Statement

```
DECLARE @execText nvarchar(3000)
DECLARE @Form nvarchar(200)

SET @Form=N'mail'

SET @execText = N'select t1.* from dbo.EDWordForms t1
where t1.CanonicForm in
(
    SELECT CanonicForm 
      FROM  dbo.EDWordForms t2
     WHERE t2.WordForm = '+ @Form + N')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @execText
```

Comment: even more slower, also you missed additional quotes near @Form